# GCLOUD Artifact Registry: Permissions error downloading maven dependency uploaded manually with Cloud Build

Tags: maven, google-artifact-registry

I have uploaded manually an maven dependency to my artifact repository

**From my local PC**, "mvn install" download correctly every maven dependency from the artifact repository, included my manually uploaded dependency.

---

mvn -U clean  install -DskipTests=true

[INFO] Scanning for projects...

[INFO]

[INFO] -----------------< com.healthcentrix.prevvy:frontend >------------------

[INFO] Building frontend 2.1-SNAPSHOT

[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------

Downloading from cloud-artifacts: artifactregistry://us-central1-maven.pkg.dev/prevvy1/artifacts/org/moxieapps/gwt/highcharts/1.7.2/highcharts-1.7.2.pom
Downloaded from cloud-artifacts: artifactregistry://us-central1-maven.pkg.dev/prevvy1/artifacts/org/moxieapps/gwt/highcharts/1.7.2/highcharts-1.7.2.pom (401 B at 90 B/s)

Downloading from cloud-artifacts: artifactregistry://us-central1-maven.pkg.dev/prevvy1/artifacts/org/moxieapps/gwt/highcharts/1.7.2/highcharts-1.7.2.jar
Downloaded from cloud-artifacts: artifactregistry://us-central1-maven.pkg.dev/prevvy1/artifacts/org/moxieapps/gwt/highcharts/1.7.2/highcharts-1.7.2.jar (521 kB at 376 kB/s)

---

**From Cloud Build or cloud-build-local**, we got an permission error

---

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project frontend: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.healthcentrix.prevvy:frontend:jar:2.1-SNAPSHOT:
```

Failed to collect dependencies at org.moxieapps.gwt:highcharts:jar:1.7.2:
Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.moxieapps.gwt:highcharts:jar:1.7.2:
Could not transfer artifact org.moxieapps.gwt:highcharts:pom:1.7.2 from/to cloud-artifacts (artifactregistry://us-central1-maven.pkg.dev/prevvy1/artifacts):
Permission denied on remote repository (or it may not exist).
The request had no credentials because none were available from the environment.
Ensure that either 1) You are logged into gcloud or 2) Application default credentials are setup (see https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information). 403 Forbidden
Step #0: [builder] [ERROR] {"error":"Permission "artifactregistry.repositories.downloadArtifacts" denied on resource "projects/prevvy1/locations/us-central1/repositories/artifacts" (or it may not exist)"}

---

Our Cloud build Project service account has every Artifact Registry permission, and is downloading the rest of depedencies excluding this specific artifact, which was uploaded manually

is necessary to give some specific permissions to this specific artifact? how?

Thanks in advance for any guidance
Regards

Comment: Make sure you have already integrated the AR to Cloud build. More details may be gathered from the "[Integrating with Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/configure-cloud-build#maven)" documentation page. And here is how you [Grant Permission for Artifact Registry](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/access-control#grant) whether it be project wide, repository specific, etc.

Comment: Cloud build service for our project account xxxxxxx@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com has following permissions rolesArtifact Registry Administrator
Artifact Registry Reader
Artifact Registry Repository Administrator
Artifact Registry Service Agent
Artifact Registry Writer
Cloud Build Service Account
Kubernetes Engine Developer
Secret Manager Secret Accessor . Indeed, cloudbuild is able to access to artifacts in this specific repository, but is not able to access to this specific artifact. I uploaded manually this aritfact with mvn deploy from my pc and my gcloud account.

Comment: Have you also signed up on this [form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSf5q3CeDna_c27ifadF1KO17W3PrYO91w-UI-jjUdnvGS1cmQ/formResponse) since this is in Alpha?